# Need Help Resolving POST Bad Request Error 400 in WooCommerce Order Expense Update Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on developing a custom form within WooCommerce that enables our delivery personnel to update expenses related to specific orders. The idea is to allow them to input additional expenses, such as taxi fares, and have these expenses associated with a particular order.

The form is designed to collect three pieces of information:

1. Order ID: The unique identifier for the order they wish to update.
2. Expense Amount: The cost of the additional expense incurred. Expense
3. Reason: A brief description or reason for the expense.

Once the delivery personnel submit this form, the data should be stored as metadata for the specified order, allowing for accurate expense tracking and management.

I have successfully built the form, but I've encountered a persistent issue. Whenever I attempt to submit the form, it returns a "POST Bad Request Error 400."

I have provided the code I'm using for the form, both in JavaScript and PHP, in the hope that the community can help me identify the root cause of this issue and guide me on how to resolve it. Any assistance and guidance on what I can do to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form id="expense_form" class="expense_form">
    Order Number<input class="exp_order_no" id="exp_order_no" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Enter the Order Number" required >
Expense Amount<input class="expense_amt" id="expense_amt" type="text"  pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Enter the expense amt" required>
Expense Reason<input class="expense_reason" id="expense_reason" type="textarea" placeholder="Enter Message" required>
   <button class="exp_but" id="exp_but">Submit</button>
    </form>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#expense_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
var orderid  = $('#exp_order_no').val();
var expense  = $('#expense_amt').val();
var expense_reason  = $('#expense_reason').val();
console.log (orderid);
console.log (expense);
console.log (expense_reason);
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
type: 'POST',
data: {
action: 'update_custom_field_order_expense',
orderid: orderid,
expense: expense,
expense_reason:expense_reason
},
success: function( response ) {
console.log( 'Custom field updated successfully.' );
},
error: function( response ) {
console.log( 'Failed to update custom field.' );
}
});
});
});
</script>

<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_custom_field_order_expense', 'update_custom_field_order_expense' );
function update_custom_field_order_expense() {
$order_id = $_POST['orderid'];
$order_expense = $_POST['expense'];
$order_expense_reason = $_POST['expense_reason'];
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
//$current_date = date_i18n( 'j F, Y', strtotime( $current_date_time ) );
$order->update_meta_data( 'Driver Expense', $order_expense );
$order->update_meta_data( 'Driver Expense Reason',$order_expense_reason);
$order->save();
wp_send_json_success();
} ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help and expertise!

Comment: Please check out my below suggested answer. It might be helpful to you.

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani Hi, thank you for your help, it's working!

Comment: It's great to hear from you @rishikesh, and I hope you'll upvote my answer so that others are able to find it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possibly due to you have used only `wp_ajax` hook which is used for authenticated (logged-in) users. You need to use `wp_ajax_nopriv` as well for both logged-in and non-logged-in users users.

Please try out the below code:

**functions.php** (Enqueue JS file and localize that file to use ajax_url in our js file.)

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'form-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', [ 'jquery' ], '1.0.0', false );
    wp_localize_script(
        'form-script',
        'customObj',
        [
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts_styles' );
```

**custom.js** (submit form with ajax)

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#expense_form").on("submit", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var orderid = $("#exp_order_no").val();
      var expense = $("#expense_amt").val();
      var expense_reason = $("#expense_reason").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: customObj.ajax_url,  // ajax-url
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          action: "update_custom_field_order_expense",
          orderid: orderid,
          expense: expense,
          expense_reason: expense_reason,
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log("Custom field updated successfully.");
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log("Failed to update custom field.");
        },
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**functions.php** (ajax hooks)

```
// For logged in users.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_custom_field_order_expense', 'update_custom_field_order_expense' );
// For logged-in and non-logged-in users.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_custom_field_order_expense', 'update_custom_field_order_expense' );
function update_custom_field_order_expense() {
    $order_id             = $_POST['orderid'];
    $order_expense        = $_POST['expense'];
    $order_expense_reason = $_POST['expense_reason'];
    // your code for woocommerce.

    wp_send_json_success();
}
```

It is working for me. Please let me know if this solution working for you or not.
Change your file name and theme path according to your current theme.